# Can't import file from live site to local site on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, localhost, mamp

I'm trying to setup my local site, but I'm having a weird issue happen to me. I am using the WP plugin called all-in-one. I copied the paid plugin files from the live site to the local site and it seems to be working fine. The problem is, when I got to import the live site's file to the local one, I get a message that reads **"Unable to open file for reading. File: x.wpress"**

Now, I read from the dev that this could be happening for a number of reasons like:

- memory_limit in PHP is not large enough to accommodate copying the
  file
- max_execution_time in PHP exceeds when copying the file
- hosting provider restrictions: there are so many here but the most
  common one is a limit imposed on the max size of a file

I did upgraded the upload max filesize on my local site to 2GB, but I used a plugin because for some reason the changes weren't being updated when using local files like wpconfig.php or php.ini. The fixes I've seen involve editing those files, but I'm not sure if I'm editing the wrong versions of said files (?) because the changes never took place. I am using MAMP and editing the files inside htdocs.

[image: import tab on local host WP dashboard]

[image: error log from trying to upload the import]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is 1 solution how you can change the LIMIT in Plugin All in One

go to Plugins => Editor and select All-in-One WP Migration as shown above. Once the plugin is loaded in the editor, click on the constants.php file from the right side:
[image: editor]

Now it’s time to edit the code to increase the Upload size limit. Go to line no 284 and you will see Max File Size text. You need to add 536870912 * 20 from bellow to change the upload size limit as shown below:
[image: increase]

Now you must click on the Update button to save the above actions.
Once saving is done, you will be able to restore any size of backup using the All-in-One WP Migration plugin in WordPress.
[image: changed]

Or you can change the same directly in file
wp-content => Plugins => all-in-one-wp-migration/constants.php

Check please if it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

I edited the .htaccess file under MAMP/htdocs/TestSite with these php values and just changed the numbers on it to fit my site. For some reason it decided to work this time.

- php_value upload_max_filesize 128M
- php_value post_max_size 128M
- php_value memory_limit 256M
- php_value max_execution_time 300
- php_value max_input_time 300